# Car dies when turning key

Tags: battery, starting, jump-start

I have a 2017 Nissan Rogue. I get in the car and the dashboard indicates my door is open I shut the door, everything is fine. But when I put the key into the Ignition and go to start it the car completely dies no lights on the dashboard, no turnover, no dashboard lights, absolutely nothing.. The only way I have found to to get my car started is to have it jump started. Had my battery alternator and starter checked and all are in perfect working order battery is only 2 months old.. Why does it keep doing this doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Where exactly do you connect both jump leads to on your car?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check all the connections from the battery to their respective homes. Either one of the connections is loose (not completely tight), or there's corrosion between the cable and the connection.

Basically what is happening is, one of those connections is bad. It will pass enough power to get the vehicle electronics and lighting up and running, but as soon as you try to pass the power needed to run the starter under load, the connection is lost. It only takes just a little bit of jiggle on any connection point to get it to pass the lower power amount.